# Conditional in perl regex replacement

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to return different replacement results with a perl regex one-liner if it matches a group. So far I've got this:

```
echo abcd |  perl -pe "s/(ab)(cd)?/defined($2)?\1\2:''/e"
```

But I get

```
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "1\"
(Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "1\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

If the input is `abcd` I want to get `abcd` out, if it's `ab` I want to get an empty string. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

You used regex atoms `\1` and `\2` (match what the first or second capture captured) outside of a regex pattern. You meant to use `$1` and `$2` (as you did in another spot).

Further more, dollar signs inside double-quoted strings have meaning to your shell. It's best to use single quotes around your program<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
echo abcd | perl -pe's/(ab)(cd)?/defined($2)?$1.$2:""/e'
```

Simpler:

```
echo abcd | perl -pe's/(ab(cd)?)/defined($2)?$1:""/e'
```

Simpler:

```
echo abcd | perl -pe's/ab(?!cd)//'
```

---

1. Either avoid single-quotes in your program<sup>[2]</sup>, or use `'\''` to "escape" them.
2. You can usually use `q{}` instead of single-quotes. You can also switch to using double-quotes. Inside of double-quotes, you can use `\x27` for an apostrophe.

Comment: Thanks. This is a simplified version of a more complex regex, so I can't use the 'simpler' approach in my more complex problem. Why does it work with single quotes on the outside but not with double quotes? I get a syntax error with `echo abcd |  perl -pe "s/(ab)(cd)?/defined($2)?$1.$2:''/e"` but not with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Why torture yourself, just use a branch reset.

Find `(?|(abcd)|ab())`
Replace `$1`

Answer (score 0):

And a couple of even better ways

Find `abcd(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|ab`
Replace `""`

Find `(?:abcd)*\Kab`
Replace `""`

These use regex wisely.
There is really no need nowadays to have to use the *eval* form
of the regex substitution construct `s///e` in conjunction with defined().
This is especially true when using the perl command line.

Good luck...