# How do I change and delete characters in one line?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get this code in one line using Perl.

```
$sdn = '"OMC=1,IONU=1,RACK=3,SR=6,SLOT=8,LPRU=1"';  # Format: Remove "=". Replace "," by "."
$sdn =~ s/[,]/./g; #tr[,][.];
$sdn =~ s/[=]//g;
$sdn =~ s/["]//g;
print $sdn;
```

Online perl editor: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php

Comment: Because my answer was downvoted, I give you a solution in comment, instead of the 3 lines, use only this one: `$sdn =~  s/(,)|[="]/$1?'.':''/eg;` that does exactly the same

Comment: Look, there is a post on exactly what you are asking for - [Conditional in perl regex replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616380/conditional-in-perl-regex-replacement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you go by inbuilt translation `tr`? First part of my answer contains your solution, and next part is mine with translation.

```
my $sdn = '"OMC=1,IONU=1,RACK=3,SR=6,SLOT=8,LPRU=1"';  # Format: Remove "=". Replace "," by "."
$sdn =~ s/[,]/./g; #tr[,][.];
$sdn =~ s/[=]//g;
$sdn =~ s/["]//g;
print $sdn;            # OMC1.IONU1.RACK3.SR6.SLOT8.LPRU1

# re-assigned the same thing and used translation
$sdn = '"OMC=1,IONU=1,RACK=3,SR=6,SLOT=8,LPRU=1"';  # Format: Remove "=". Replace "," by "."
$sdn =~ tr/,="/./d;    # OMC1.IONU1.RACK3.SR6.SLOT8.LPRU1
print $sdn;
```

Comment: I used Toto solution: `$sdn =~ s/(,)|[="]/$1?'.':''/eg;` [TR vs S perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638205/whats-the-difference-between-tr-and-s-when-using-regex-in-perl) TR is faster than S for substitutions so I will change my solution to your code, Thanks!!

Comment: @DavidGonzálezArias: Toto's solution works well, but translation is faster than substitution. Also, in case, if you need to add other chars also, you can add in translation without worrying about to add any condition in substitution.