# Unix : Find and replace consecutive commas to consecutive pipelines

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

I'm converting a double quoted CSV to pipeline delimited txt file in Unix.
I have used the following sed command to replace "," into | then remove starting and ending double quote.

```
sed -e 's/","/|/g' -e 's/"//g' filenm.csv > filenm.txt
```

But the file seems to have consecutive commas without double quotes and they are not getting replaced.

```
Col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8
Val1|val2|val3,,,,val7|val8
```

Now I want to convert all these consecutive commas to consecutive pipelines as they indicate empty or null fields.

And other fields also have commas inside field values which should not be altered.

I tried using below for that, but not working.

```
sed -e 's/,{1,\}/|{1,\}/g' filenm.csv > filenm.txt
```

sample csv file opened in notepad:

```
"ID","Name","DOB","Age","Address","City","State","Country","Phone number"
"123","ABC","12/20/2020","15","No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT",,,,"9999999999"
"456","DEF","12/20/2020",,,,,"test-country","9999999999"
"465","XYZ",,,"No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT",,,,"9999999999"
```

I hope this helps to reproduce the issue and resolve.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you post the original file?

Comment: sure, i have added the sample file. hope this helps! Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the perl command works perfectly but one small issue - when there is 0 in a field, it skips that and the field content gets moved by one field...

i.e. when file looks like this:
`"ID","Name","DOB","Age","Address","City","State","Country","Phone number"
"123","ABC","12/20/2020","0","No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT",,,,"9999999999"`

the perl cmd u have provided givfes the below result:

`ID|Name|DOB|Age|Address|City|State|Country|Phone number
123|ABC|12/20/2020|||No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT||||9999999999`
Kindly import this sample in Excel for good ref.

Comment: yeah i was just trying out and analyzing the issue....

Comment: No what I have placed is Unix output

Comment: You could see three pipelines instead of two in the data: `12/20/2020|||No.38`

Comment: Yes, the problem was that `0` evaluates to *false*, so the correct way is [using `defined($1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43616504/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's/"([^"]*)"|,/defined($1) ? $1 : "|"/ge' filenm.csv > filenm.txt
```

**Details**:

- `"([^"]*)"|,` - the regex pattern that matches `"`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than `"` and then matches a `"`, or just matches a `,` in all other contexts
- `defined($1) ? $1 : "|"` - RHS, replacement, that replaces the match either with Group 1 value (if Group 1 was matched) or with a `|` (if the `,` was matched)
- `ge` - `g` stands for `global` (replaces all occurrences) and `e` makes Perl treat the RHS as a Perl expression.

See an [online test](https://ideone.com/tAsmN9):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='"ID","Name","DOB","Age","Address","City","State","Country","Phone number"
"123","ABC","12/20/2020","0","No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT",,,,"9999999999"'
perl -pe 's/"([^"]*)"|,/defined($1) ? $1 : "|"/ge' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ID|Name|DOB|Age|Address|City|State|Country|Phone number
123|ABC|12/20/2020|0|No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT||||9999999999
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(("[^",]*",+)*"[^",]*),/\1\n/;ta;y/,\n/|,/' file
```

Iteratively replace `,`'s between `"`'s with newlines, then translate `,`'s for `|`'s and newlines for `,`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk -F \" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /^[,]{2,}$/) { $i="," } } OFS="\"";gsub("\",\"","\"|\"",$0)}1' sample.csv
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F \" '{  # Set the field delimiter to double quote
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
               if ($i ~ /^[,]{2,}$/) { 
                  $i="," # Loop through each field and if is contains 2 or more commas, set that field to one comma
               } 
             } 
             OFS="\"";
             gsub("\",\"","\"|\"",$0) # Substitute "," for "|"
           }1' sample.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for that following way. Let `file.txt` content be

```
"ID","Name","DOB","Age","Address","City","State","Country","Phone number"
"123","ABC","12/20/2020","15","No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT",,,,"9999999999"
"456","DEF","12/20/2020",,,,,"test-country","9999999999"
"465","XYZ",,,"No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT",,,,"9999999999"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\"";OFS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2){$i=gensub(/,/,"|","g",$i)};print $0}' file.txt
```

output

```
ID|Name|DOB|Age|Address|City|State|Country|Phone number
123|ABC|12/20/2020|15|No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT||||9999999999
456|DEF|12/20/2020|||||test-country|9999999999
465|XYZ|||No.38,3rd st, RRR NNN, TRT||||9999999999
```

I assumed that first and last column is never empty. I use `"` as field separator and then in every odd field (these contain solely `,`) I change all `,` to `|`. Finally I print whole such altered line.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*